# Shared Preference value to API Get method

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to android and retrofit.i want get userID stored in shared preference into api call.
i have developed this.how to replace {uid} with shared preference value

API interface

```
        @GET("/Account/{uid}/friends")
        Call<List<TblFriends>> getfriends(@Path("uid") String uid);
```

Activity

```
 public void getFriends()
   {
    Api api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(Api.class);

    Call<List<TblFriends>> call = api.getfriends();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TblFriends>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<TblFriends>> call, Response<List<TblFriends>> response)

        {

            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                List<TblFriends> tblFriends = response.body();
                friendsAdapter.setData(tblFriends);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);

                //    Log.e("success",response.body().toString());
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<TblFriends>> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("failure",t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Shared preference code is on login activity for to get userid ,this is the full code in login

```
public static String globalPreferenceName = "proofile";


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
        getSharedPreferences(globalPreferenceName,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
       //UserID
        editor.putString("token",s);  
       editor.putString("token2",JWTUtils.getJSon(token));
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: Post your shared preference code.

Comment: Do you know how to get value from SharedPreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get your globalPreferenceName shared preference as below.
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(globalPreferenceName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

By using sharedPref get your token2 as below.
String uid = sharedPref.getString("token2"), defaultValue);

Then use uid as below,
 Call<List<TblFriends>> call = api.getfriends(uid);
```